# apache configuring subdomains via wildcard while preventing subsubdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, subdomain

I have subdomains coinfigured with apache via the wildcard:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
...
```

That works perfect, except that it also enables subsubdomains. E.g.: www.test.server.com

How can I make sure only `subdomains` are valid and `subsubdomains` not?

Comment: rewrite rules for subsub?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `ServerAlias` only support wildcard, not regex. You should do it with `mod_rewrite`, something like this:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</Virtualhost>
```